# How to load a base template in code igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, templates

I'm new to working with CI and I have a question. More like a design method suggestion. I want to create a base template for static pages. Basically I want to load doc type, head, and the body but nothing else. I want the content to be loaded by whatever class/function I call via the URL. I know I can do this with a HTML template and str_replace() but is there a better way or some fancy CI method I'm not familiar with?

Here is what I have so far and it works but it's not the best.

```
class Sandbox extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        //echo "hello world?"; 
    }

    public function load($what){
        if ($what == 'something'){

            if (!file_exists('application/views/content/'.$what.'.php')){
                // Whoops, we don't have a page for that!
                show_404();
            }
            $data = array();
            $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
            $this->load->view('content/'.$what, $data);
            $this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);
        }
        else { // Default load

            $data = array();
            $data['message'] = 'Hello World';
            //$this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
            $this->load->view('content/sandbox', $data);
            //$this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);
        }
    }
}
```

When I load the view method it seems to work but I had to add the doctype and head to the template. I would prefer to load those seperately so do not have to create multiple headers. What I am looking for is a way to specifically load parts of the page and whatever scripts/css that are required for that given page.

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function names in the controller are references to the url eg:

```
www.ci.com/sandbox/load
```

The above url would load `function load()` inside the sandbox controller.

To create a template you can just create a view with the basics that you want and then pass the content to that view eg:

```
function home(){
$data['content'] = $this->load->view('home_content',,TRUE);
this->load->view('template', $data)
}
```

By using `TRUE` in the 3rd argument you are returning the data rather than displaying it.

Then in the template file just `echo $content;`
You could also create separate head files and other files to include in your template using the same method ie:

```
function home(){
$data['content'] = $this->load->view('home_content',,TRUE);
$data['head'] = $this->load->view('head',,TRUE);
this->load->view('template', $data);
}
```

You can also pass the data variable to views that you are returning ie:

```
$data['content'] = $this->load->view('home_content',,TRUE);
$data['admin_script'] = $this->load->view('admin_script',,TRUE);
$data['head'] = $this->load->view('head',$data,TRUE);
```

I hope this helps! :)

**ALSO**

If you want to load different pages you should create separate functions for them and create  a new routing rule : [Codeigniter: URI ROUTING](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html)

Comment: $data['content'] = $this->load->view('home_content',,TRUE); Returns the data does that include html tags?

Comment: It will include everything that you have put in that file. Think of it like you're using `include`.

Comment: Thanks that is handy and I can use it to do what I want. I just tested :D